Change the time of a specific scheduled notification in flutter_local_notifications with Firebase Messaging
A message will come to the phone via Firebase messaging. There will be data in this message. Can I change the time that the notification will be displayed according to this data, which was previously set on the phone with the flutter_local_notifications package and should send a notification at a certain time?
I think it works when the app is open or in the background, but is there a way to do it when the app is completely closed?
